# Prevent images to download again after going back or terminating app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

First of all I want to say, I didn't find anyting about it on this site.

I want to save `NSURL` into `NSUserDefaults` to prevent loading image on every app open or the view open. I tried to achieve it like this but for some reason I can't. At least I think thats what should do it:

```
let productImageref = productsValue[indexPath.row]["Products"] as? String


        cell.snusProductImageView.image = nil
        if let url =  self.productsValue[indexPath.row]["imageUrl"] as? NSURL {
            cell.snusProductImageView.kf_showIndicatorWhenLoading = true
            var storedUrl = defaults.objectForKey("imageUrl") as? NSURL
            cell.snusProductImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(storedUrl)
        }
        else {
            FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(productImageref!).png").downloadURLWithCompletion({(url, error)in

                if error != nil{
                    print(error)
                    return
                }else{
                    self.productsValue[indexPath.row]["imageUrl"] = url

                    self.defaults.setURL(url, forKey: "imageUrl")

                    self.productstable.reloadData()
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        })
                }
                })
        }
```

If I am wrong then please correct me. Should saving the url-s into `userdefaults` do the trick?

What exactly I am doing wrong here? Maybe it is better to save it into `CoreData` but I thought that it would be overkill.

Why the **KingFisher** or **SDWebImages** library is not caching it?

Comment: I highly recommend taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943645/uploading-downloading-multiple-images-the-right-way and using that in conjunction with a tool like SDWebImage or PINRemoteImage. There are better solutions than CoreData and `NSUserDefaults` for this application :)

Comment: Ooh.. finally something that is not downvote. So according what you said I understand that the download url never changes? So I don't have to store them into array and into userdefaults?

Comment: Nope, both URL types (`gs://` and `https://`) are stable. You'll want to use the public `https://` one for a third-party image loading lib or for caching. The Realtime Database also has offline persistence, so you won't have to fetch the URL on cold start :)

Comment: The Github one has `Cache-Control: max-age=300` while Firebase Storage doesn't have cache control set by default (you can set it when you upload the file, or change it by updating metadata), so I assume that's why KingFisher isn't caching it.

Comment: Thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to store URL like below:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setURL(yourURL:NSURL?, forKey: "imageURL")
```

And read `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.URLForKey("imageURL")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that might help: use `synchronize` after saving something to defaults and use `URLForKey` to get it back.

(And check that the thing you're saving really is a `NSURL`.)

Here's sample code that works in a project; compare it to yours (NSUserDefaults is broken for playgrounds.):

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let components = NSURLComponents(string: "http://localhost/"),
        url = components.URL {
        defaults.setURL(url, forKey: "imageUrl")
        defaults.synchronize()
        if let fetchedURL = defaults.URLForKey("imageUrl") {
            print("\(fetchedURL) returned")
        } else {
            print("No URL in defaults")
        }
    } else {
        print("Bad components")
    }
    print(defaults.dictionaryRepresentation())
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, you want to save multiple images url in NSUserDefaults

```
 let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/")
    var array = [NSString]()
    array.append((url?.absoluteString)!)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(array, forKey: "image")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    if let fetchedURL = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("image") as! [String]? {
        print("\(fetchedURL[0]) returned")
        let fileUrl = NSURL(string: fetchedURL[0])
        print(fileUrl)
    } else {
        print("No URL in defaults")
    }
```

print results

http://localhost/ returned

Optional(http://localhost/)